# Using intl-tel-input and vuejs2 together

Tags: jquery, vuejs2, vue-directives

I am trying to implement https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input with `vuejs2`.

If I add inside one jQuery`document.ready`, `$('#phone').intlTelInput({ options...})`

Everything works as expected but when I'm trying to fetch the value of the input field and some `boolean` valid property, I am always checking the value one step behind.

My checking method looks like:

```
    validatePhoneNumber: function() {
        var validPhoneNo = $("#phone").intlTelInput("isValidNumber");
        var phoneNo = $("#phone").intlTelInput("getNumber");
        console.log(phoneNo + ' -> ' + validPhoneNo); //this line returns values one step behind
        bus.$emit('validate-phone', validPhoneNo)
    }
```

The HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" @keydown="validatePhoneNumber" :class="{validInput: validPhone }" type="text" name="phone" value="" id="phone" :phone_number="phone_number">
```

I believe the solution would be to create a new directive for this matter, and I tried the following:

Removed the part where I instantiated the `intlTelInput` on `document.ready` and made this instead:

```
Vue.directive('telinput', {
    bind: function(el) {
        $(el).intlTelInput({
            //options here...
    }
});
```

and added `v-telinput` to my `HTML` code above.

with this, nothing seems to work.

What am I missing there?

Comment: Use a wrapper component instead of a directive. https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html

Comment: I did tried that, I got stuck into some other (non-related) issue where I couldn't use the component inside the main element `#app`...

Comment: It's a bad idea to use VueJS and jQuery together. Instead you should be looking into something like this that is built for Vue: https://github.com/EducationLink/vue-tel-input

Comment: hey, do u fix it??

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @keyup instead of @keydown

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers. Once you have enough reputation, you will be able to post comments. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/20230419)