# Make VueJS and jQuery play nice

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2

This question is related/similar to [Using intl-tel-input and vuejs2 together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42792983/2012740) , which is still unanswered.

And [VueJS Use prop as data-attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43236848/2012740) which has a solution, but explains a bit the "environment".

So, long story short, I am dynamically setting up a new bootstrap tab (Title and URL), and then trying to (re)bind some functionality using `jQuery`.

Adding the following line https://github.com/thecodeassassin/bootstrap-remote-data/blob/master/js/bootstrap-remote-tabs.js#L258 in my Vue method will apply the functionality, but only if I trigger the change twice.

The same issue with the first (unanswered) question.

Could someone explain a bit how the things work between `vueJS` and `jQuery` ? And how to solve things, hopefully without needing to rewrite jQuery packages.

If I `console.log` my variables just seem one step behind.

LE:

I have prepared a Pen for the related mentioned issue:
https://codepen.io/AngelinCalu/pen/LWvwNq

Comment: Where is your Vue code? Can you please be more specific with your question? in my experience i have only had to use jquery with Vue in order to take advantage of jquery datepicker.

Comment: Need some code, we can't help you without knowing how you did it....

Comment: Please consider the code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236848/vuejs-use-prop-as-data-attribute-value, 

with the mention that I am using https://github.com/thecodeassassin/bootstrap-remote-data, 

and with `var remoteTabsPluginLoaded = new RemoteTabs(customSettings);` added in `showDetail` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42938177/392102

Comment: @RoyJ For sure it's the same issue, but still very unclear in terms of what's happening there when creating a wrapper component. Could you elaborate into some answer maybe giving some generic example.

Comment: Your Codepen seems to be working properly--what is the issue there?

Comment: @Terry Open the Console and check the log. You will see that it's one step behind the input.

Comment: What if you listen to the onInput event (i.e. `@input`) instead of onKeydown? It worked for me.

Comment: @Terry WOW!! :O 

I wasn't expecting that. Why does it work? How about if I have a `@onclick `trigger as in the other example?

Comment: From which element do you intend to bind the click even to? Another component? Another DOM element that is not part of VueJS virtual DOM?

Comment: Well, The phone validation example is somehow an abbandoned idea. I am now trying to create a remote bootstrap tab dinamically using vueJS. And then load the contents using some jquery plugin. The links are all in the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The way to make Vue play nicely with other DOM-manipulating toolkits is to completely segregate them: if you are going to use jQuery to manipulate a DOM  widget, you do not also use Vue on it (and vice-versa).

A [wrapper component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) acts as a bridge, where Vue can interact with the component and the component can manipulate its internal DOM elements using jQuery (or whatever).

jQuery selectors outside of [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) are a bad code smell. Your `validatePhoneNumber` uses a selector and a DOM-manipulating call, but you are using Vue to handle `keydown` events. You need to handle everything on this widget with jQuery. Don't use Vue to set its class or phone_number or handle its events. Those are all DOM manipulations. As I mentioned, if you wrap it in a component, you can pass props to the component and from those props you can use jQuery to set class and phone_number.

Answer (score 5):

I think the reason behind it is that [when the `keydown` event is fired](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/blob/master/src/js/intlTelInput.js#L660), the internal workings of the plugin kicks in and does not immediately expose the phone values. This results in a race condition where you prematurely retrieves the phone number value **before** it is being updated internally by the plugin itself.

This issue can simply be resolved by listening to other events, such as `keyup` or `input`:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    phone_number: "",
    validPhone: false
  },


  methods: {
    validatePhoneNumber: function() {
      var phone_element = $('#phone');
      var validPhoneNo = phone_element.intlTelInput("isValidNumber");
      var phoneNo = phone_element.intlTelInput("getNumber");
      console.log(phoneNo + ' -> ' + validPhoneNo); // I am interested in both values
    }
  },


  mounted: function() {
    $('#phone').intlTelInput({
      utilsScript: "js/utils.js",
      initialCountry: "auto",
      geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
        $.get('https://ipinfo.io', function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
          var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
          callback(countryCode);
        });
      },
      preferredCountries: []
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.10/css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.10/js/utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.10/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
      <input class="form-control" @input="validatePhoneNumber" :class="{validInput: validPhone }" name="phone" value="" ref="phone_element" :phone_number="phone_number" type="text" id="phone" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have to admit that this is still not the ideal solution, because there might still be a race condition going. The only way to make sure that no race condition exists is to wait for the plugin to trigger a custom callback once the phone number is parsed and validated, which you can listen on the input element in VueJS. Right now I see that the plugin only has a custom callback for country change.