# SelectBoxIt jq plugin not working with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, vue.js, selectboxit

There are many dynamically generated select box in a page. I want to apply the jquery ***selectBoxIt*** (http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/) plugin. I am using ***Vue js*** . Where should I put

```
$('.cl_v').selectBoxIt({ theme: 'default', 'defaultText': 'select', autoWidth: false });
```

in order to attach the plugin with the select elements? The class applied to the select box is **cl_v**. I have placed the above code in **created:** , **mounted:** and **destroyed:** . But it did not work. How can I use the plugin with Vue.js? Thanks

Comment: Look at your browser console

Comment: @BelminBedak what should I be looking for in console?

Comment: For error and post it here

Comment: Btw try to wrap this in jQuery document ready function and then put it into the mounted hook.

Comment: @BelminBedak I am not getting any errors

Comment: @BelminBedak  $(function () { $('.dropdown_cl_v').selectBoxIt({ theme: 'default', 'defaultText': 'select', autoWidth: false }); }); inside mounted is also not working

Comment: I didn't said you to do that - try like this - `mounted: function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cl_v').selectBoxIt({ theme: 'default', 'defaultText': 'select', autoWidth: false });
  });
}`

Comment: @BelminBedak tried it..still not working

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [wrapper component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html). That is how you [make VueJS and jQuery play nice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255516/392102).

If the only thing required for your `selectBoxIt` to work is the call above, you just need something like this `mounted` section:

```
mounted() {
  $(this.el).selectBoxIt({ theme: 'default', 'defaultText': 'select', autoWidth: false });
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example of using selectboxit with vuejs

Comment: Not really; but see updated answer, and be sure to look at the JavaScript tab on the wrapper component page I linked.

Comment: I got the plugin style to work when I put $(...).selectBoxIt({ theme: 'default', 'defaultText': 'select', autoWidth: false }); in updated: hook. But the selectChange method which was firing when a different option is selected is not working now. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there any way you could put together a runnable snippet or fiddle? It would be worth putting up a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official document: [Wrapper Component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html)

here is the sample code:

```js
Vue.component('selectBoxIt', {
  props: ['options', 'value'],
  template: '#selectBoxIt-template',
  mounted: function () {
    var vm = this
    $(this.$el)
      .val(this.value)
      .trigger('change')
      // emit event on change.
      .on('change', function () {
        vm.$emit('input', this.value)
      })
  },
  watch: {
    value: function (value) {
      // update value
      $(this.$el).val(value)
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#demo-template',
  data: {
    fruits: [{id:1,name:'apple'},{id:2,name:'banana'}],
    selectId: 0
  },
  mounted: function() {
    $('#fruits').selectBoxIt();
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.8.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.css" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.8.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="demo-template">
<div>
  <p>selectId: {{ selectId }}</p>
  <selectBoxIt id="fruits" :options="fruits" v-model="selectId">
  </selectBoxIt>
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="selectBoxIt-template">
  <select>
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.id">{{ option.name }}</option>
  </select>
</script>
```

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5qnqkjr1/131/