# Using hasClass with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I know this setup I have isn't ideal however I need to check the class of an input element. I have just started using Vue.js on a new project however we have a form validation library that has to be used that uses jQuery.

The validation library I am using adds a class to an input if it doesn't fit some validation requirements.

If I was using jQuery I could just use hasClass to check if the input element had a specific class.

In Vue I am unsure how I can check if an element has a class though?

Here is an example method of what I'd like to achieve:

```
      methods: {
        nextStep: function() {
          const element = this.$el.querySelector("#conversation__tram-1 input");
          if (element has the class of is-valid) {
            Do something
          }

        },
      },
```

As you can see I'd like to check whether or not the input field has a class of `is-valid`. Can you think of any way I can do this with Vue.js? Thanks.

Comment: Another thing you can use to make this code more Vue-like is `ref` for the element: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Answer (score 18):

You can use the element's [`classList` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
if (element.classList.contains('is-valid')) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: If you don't need IE9 support then you're good: https://caniuse.com/#search=classList

Comment: Yeah, if you really need `IE9` support, there's a Polyfill you can use on the page I linked.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the native `vue.js` functions involve manipulating the data behind the DOM, not the DOM itself.

There are multiple ways you can achieve this,
You can use Vue class binding, which is two-way. So you once you initialize binding then you can build an API to expose that.

Have you tried this?

```
if (this.$els.elementNameHere.className.match(/\bmyclass\b/)) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is already involved, just use its `hasClass` the way you already know how.

```
    nextStep: function() {
      const element = this.$el.querySelector("#conversation__tram-1 input");
      if ($(element).hasClass('is-valid')) {
        Do something
      }
    },
```

Vue does not provide any special DOM manipulation routines, because in Vue, you aren't generally supposed to be manipulating the DOM. There are some carved-out exceptions, but this isn't really one. :) The key to mixing jQuery and Vue is that you must be careful to [separate what jQuery controls from what Vue controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255516/392102) so they don't step on each other's toes. Not much harm here in simply reading the DOM as long as you don't expect Vue to be updating it.