# angular 1.x modules in Vue.js

Tags: angularjs, webpack, module, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm writing a new project in Vue.js that has dependencies on older angular 1.x modules.

Is it possible/realistic to import an angular 1.x module/directive into my Vue.js application?  Can webpack transpile any angular code into vanilla?

Comment: possible yes, realistic... depends on the time you want to spend on it. If you don't have a lot of angular module, just recreate them in vue js, will be faster than creating a webpack or gulp module to do it.

Comment: there are a few of them.  Re-writing them is not an option for me.  They are very complex and critical.  I just need to use/include them in my application

Comment: You will probably need to write wrapper components. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255516/392102