# Vue v-on:click fails to work after build

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, vue.js

I am using the example on here [Vue slide example](https://codepen.io/eehayman/pres/WReQmv?editors=1010)

Integrated in my angular template.

When I run `ng serve` and all works fine, but after I ran `ng build` and then start it with `ng serve` or from the dist folder with `npm start` without have done any code modification the content is loaded but is not possible to change to the next slide clicking on the buttons.

I have found that if I change the id of the main div element in that case `<div id="app"` changed to `<div id="app2"` and also in the script `el: '#app'` to `el: '#app2'` it will work again but only for the first time too before run `ng build`.

More details: Looks like that the v-on:click is not called 
    v-on:click="updateSlide(index)"

On the html side:

```
 <div class="pagination-container">
                <span class="pagination-item" 
                    v-for="(slide, index) in slides"
                    v-bind:class="{ active: index === currentSlide }"
                    v-on:click="updateSlide(index)"></span>
            </div>
```

on the script side:

```
var appVue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        currentSlide: 0,
        isPreviousSlide: false,
        isFirstLoad: true,
        slides: [ ...]
},
methods: {
        updateSlide: function (index) {
            console.log("move to other slide"); 
            index < this.currentSlide ? this.isPreviousSlide = true : 
this.isPreviousSlide = false;
            this.currentSlide = index;
            this.isFirstLoad = false; 
        }
    }
});
```

Any idea why this issue with the element id of the div ?

Thanks!

Comment: It is very probable that Angular and Vuejs don't work together natively. https://github.com/ngVue/ngVue

Comment: Thanks! I am with Angular 4, maybe is some incompatibility, but it works fine when I change the DIV id of the Vue element and run it from memory with angular `ng serve` only after running `ng build` it fails to work anymore

Comment: You should maybe integrate VueJS directly in Angular, or let Angular dying quietly and pass everything in VueJS ;-)

Comment: If  at least I could find a work around for now would be better.. I am just not getting what happens to the vue div id when `ng build` is running...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Angular and Vue want to control the DOM, but they can't. You have to segregate them, just as you have to do to [use jQuery with Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255516/392102) or [Boostrap with Angular](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), so that only one or the other is controlling any particular bit of the DOM. If Vue is running the show, you would make [wrapper components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) to segregate the Angular bits. If (as it sounds like) Angular is running the show, you will need to make directives to segregate the Vue bits.

Comment: Thanks Roy! I will try to follow that looks to be the appropriated solution.