# How to create vuejs datepicker on vuejs 1.0.2?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker

I am new to vue js and I am trying to implement vuejs datepicker on version 1.0.27. As mentioned in the vuejs datepicker documentation. My app version is 1.0.27. I am trying to install `npm install vuejs-datepicker@0.9.9` as mentioned in the vuejs datepicker documentation.

- When installing with npm I tried placing the datepicker js file from
  the build folder inside node_modules and vue js from npmcdn.
  I got the error module is not defined. Since the datepicker js build starts as "module.exports"
- I tried with plain js and bootstrap picker files as mentioned in the example I don't get the datepicker with 1.0.2 but with 2.x

Meanwhile I tried

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965490/datepicker-with-vuejs), in the fiddle he provided,

> But he seems to be using vue js 2.x version. also in the answer as well as question

I prefer to have a solution with vuejs datepicker@0.9.9 but atleast with some other datepicker with **vuejs 1.0.27**

Comment: Hey Abel, what is not working? The installation, the import or the date picker himself?

Comment: I updated the question please check now

Comment: so where are you doing npm install? did your package json has the datepicker inside with the current version and blocked?

Comment: you dont need to update the question just keep comment here when we figure out all the stuff you edit the question and maybe I could provide an answer for you

Comment: My package.json has it "vuejs-datepicker": "^0.9.9", Also vue js "vue": "^1.0.27",

Comment: Included these files
<script src="http://localhost/trials/golf-app/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/trials/golf-app/node_modules/vuejs-datepicker/dist/build.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

First you should add the import and *then* add Datepicker to the list of components:

```
<script>
import sweetalert from 'sweetalert';
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import CreateTodo from './components/CreateTodo';    

export default {
name: 'app',
components: {
TodoList,
CreateTodo,
Datepicker
},
</script>
```