# Vue modal not rendering HTML

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue2.js, I am trying to open modal box and show content of an array.

```
<tr v-for="(sku_req,itemObjKey) in sku_requests" :key="sku_req.id">
  <td><i class="ft-eye font-medium-3 mr-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showskudetails" v-on:click="show_sku_object(itemObjKey)"></i></td>
</tr>
```

which is open modal box perfectly, but its not rendering vue variable values

Modal Box:

```
<div class="modal fade text-left" id="showskudetails" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel21" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel21">SKU Gen Request</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">Seller</div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">@{{selected_sku_req.seller_name}}</div>
                    </div>
```

Now this Modal Box when opening , its displaying like this :

```
Seller @{{selected_sku_req.seller_name}}
```

Basically selected_sku_req.seller_name is not loading

Vue Function

```
show_sku_object: function(itemObjKey){
        var self = this;
        self.selected_sku_req = self.sku_requests[itemObjKey];
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you're using Bootstrap along with Vue. That's not going to work well, since Vue isn't aware of when Bootstrap modifies the DOM.

Comment: how can I make Vue to know about Bootstrap? or somehow to render HTML again!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have Bootstrap and Vue both controlling the DOM without some kind of referee to keep them from stepping on each others' toes. See [Make VueJS and jQuery play nice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255516/392102)
.

Probably your best option is to use [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) which was created to solve this exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather complicated approach. Why not make your modal a Vue-component that renders data dynamically, like

```
<tr v-for="(sku_req,itemObjKey) in sku_requests" :key="sku_req.id">
 <td :data="sku_object.itemObjKey"><i v-on:click="openModal()"></i></td>
</tr>
```

and then refer to it in your modal

```
<div class="col-md-8" v-html="data"></div>
```

Example:
https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/10