# v-model not working with bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, datepicker

**Scenario**

I'm changing a themes default and super ugly datepicker and decided to use bootstraps datepicker, found [here](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/methods.html). The problem im having is that my 'v-model' attribute isnt doing anything when i use the datepicker, but its doing something when i type in the input field.

**Code**

```
// Html
<div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
    <input v-model="user.date_of_birth" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" id="date-of-birth" class="form-control datepicker" name="date">
    @{{ user.date_of_birth }}
</div>

// javascript
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    setDate: new Date()
});
```

the datepicker works and is initialised and it changes the value on the input field. My problem is that v-model is completely ignored unless i physically type in the field!

**Question**

How do i get v-model to work with this datepicker?
Is there a specific reason that v-model isn't working with this datepicker?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240789/make-vuejs-and-jquery-play-nice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use v-model like this：

```
<div id="app">
    <my-date-picker v-model="date"></my-date-picker>
    {{date}}
</div>


Vue.component('my-date-picker',{
    template: '<input type="text" v-datepicker class="datepicker" :value="value" @input="update($event.target.value)">',
    directives: {
        datepicker: {
            inserted (el, binding, vNode) {
                $(el).datepicker({
                    autoclose: true,
                    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                }).on('changeDate',function(e){
                    vNode.context.$emit('input', e.format(0))
                })
            }
        }
    },
    props: ['value'],
    methods: {
        update (v){
            this.$emit('input', v)
        }
    }
})


var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        date: '2018-03-01'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I failed with [jacky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526987/2180787), but thanks to https://github.com/Xelia, problem sovled (even in Vue 1.0, using `ready` life cycle instead of `mounted`)

Manually update vue data in datepicker `changeDate` event listener, like this

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    startDate: '',
  },
  mounted() {
    $("#startDate").datepicker().on(
      "changeDate", () => {this.startDate = $('#startDate').val()}
    );
  },
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3a2055ub/

And by the way, if you are working on legacy company project using ES5 function instead of ES6 fat arrow function. Need to bind `this`, which is vue instance, into the function. For example:

```js
mounted() {
  var self = this; // the vue instance
  $("#startDate").datepicker().on(
    "changeDate", function() {self.startDate = $('#startDate').val()}
  );
},
```

Of course there are other ways to reach this goal, as [this blog written by Jason Arnold](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/es5-functions-vs-es6-fat-arrow-functions-864033baa1a)
 shows.

Reference: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4231

Probable related question: [V-model with datepicker input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957334/v-model-with-datepicker-input/60054221#60054221)

Comment: thank you very much for sharing the solution, had same issue and solved by your help! <3