# V-model with datepicker input

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Trying to build a component that works with daepicker and using v-model to bind the input value. But the input event does not appear to be firing and I can’t seem to figure out why. Here’s my component:

```
<div id="app">
    <datepicker v-model="date"></datepicker>
</div>

Vue.component('datepicker', {
        template: '<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" autocomplete="off">',
        mounted: function() {
            $(this.$el).datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                startView: 'years',
            }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
                this.$emit('input', e.format('dd/mm/yyyy'));
            });
        },
        destroyed: function () {
            $(this.$el).datepicker('destroy');
        }
    });

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        date: '2018-03-01'
    }
})
```

In addition, the following error appears in the console:

**Uncaught TypeError: this.$emit is not a function**

Comment: Are you using jQuery and Vue.js together? If so, `this` in the jQuery event handler is not the same as `this` in the Vue component context

Comment: after this code `mounted: function() {` add `var self = this` and the for the emit, use `self.$emit` meaning change: `this` to `self`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're mixing jQuery and Vue (just a guess from the code fragment), you're mixing up your contexts. One (of many) ways to fix:

```
   mounted: function() {
        const self = this;
        $(this.$el).datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startView: 'years',
        }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            self.$emit('input', e.format('dd/mm/yyyy'));
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

I failed with [jacky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526987/2180787), but thanks to https://github.com/Xelia, problem sovled (even in Vue 1.0, using `ready` life cycle instead of `mounted`)

Manually update vue data in datepicker `changeDate` event listener, like this

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    startDate: '',
  },
  mounted() {
    $("#startDate").datepicker().on(
      "changeDate", () => {this.startDate = $('#startDate').val()}
    );
  },
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3a2055ub/

And by the way, if you are working on legacy company project using ES5 function instead of ES6 fat arrow function. Need to bind `this`, which is vue instance, into the function. For example:

```js
mounted() {
  var self = this; // the vue instance
  $("#startDate").datepicker().on(
    "changeDate", function() {self.startDate = $('#startDate').val()}
  );
},
```

Of course there are other ways to reach this goal, as [this blog written by Jason Arnold](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/es5-functions-vs-es6-fat-arrow-functions-864033baa1a)
 shows.

Reference: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4231

Probable related question: [v-model not working with bootstrap datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515965/v-model-not-working-with-bootstrap-datepicker/60054372#60054372)