# vue.js conflicts with .datepicker and removes date value after changing next v-model input

Tags: jquery, laravel, vuejs2, datepicker

I have a form implemented with laravel and vue2 and it has some date fields where I'm using datepicker plugin. But problem is, when I go and type in the next (or any other) input, the value of the date field(s) becomes empty. I have tried many ways and looked for many questions and none helped.

### [See this Short Video for better understanding of the `problem`](https://youtu.be/IQe7fFwvNTM)

## ***input***

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="memo_date">Memo Date</label>
    <input v-model="form.memo_date" class="form-control demoDate2" id="memo_date" name="memo_date" type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" autocomplete="off" value="{{old('memo_date')}}">
    <span class="text-danger" v-if="errors.memo_date">@{{ errors.memo_date[0] }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="from_date">From Date</label>
    <input class="form-control demoDate2" v-model="form.from_date" @keyup.prevent="getDuration" id="from_date" name="from_date" type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" autocomplete="off">
    <span class="text-danger" v-if="errors.from_date">@{{ errors.from_date[0] }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="to_date">To Date</label>
    <input class="form-control demoDate2" v-model="form.to_date" @keyup.prevent="getDuration" id="to_date" name="to_date" type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" autocomplete="off">
    <span class="text-danger" v-if="errors.to_date">@{{ errors.to_date[0] }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="memo_no">Memo No</label>
    <input class="form-control" v-model="form.memo_no" id="memo_no" type="text" name="memo_no" value="{{ old('memo_no') }}">
    <span class="text-danger" v-if="errors.memo_no">@{{ errors.memo_no[0] }}</span>
</div>
```

## ***data and mounted function***

```js
data: {
   ...
   ...
    form: {
        attachment:'',
        memo_no:'',
        memo_date:'',
        from_date:'',
        to_date:'',
        duration:'',
        description:'',
        employees_ids:[],
    },
    errors:[]
},

mounted: function (){
    // datepicker
    $('.demoDate2').datepicker({
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        orientation: "bottom auto"
    });
}
```

***Additional Note***: I used change() event inside mounted() to alert when the date value is added using datepicker/keyboard and it fires. **BUT** when the value is removed, the event does not fire!

I have tried [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50957400/8607640) and many more but none helped. Please help me find the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @blackgreen updated question with Vue data

Comment: Maybe something causes `.datepicker()` to be re-initialised on the three `.demoDate2` fields? eg, the `mounted` function gets re-invoked.

Comment: datepicker does not work unless used inside mounted(). why would re-initialisation empty the date field value?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must bind datepicker onSelect event to update the current model.

You can see the example below.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="memo_date">Memo Date</label>
    <input v-model="form.memo_date" class="form-control demoDate2" id="memo_date" name="memo_date" type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" autocomplete="off" value="{{old('memo_date')}}">
    <span class="text-danger" v-if="errors.memo_date">@{{ errors.memo_date[0] }}</span>
</div>
```

==================================================================================

```
 data: {
       ...
       ...
        form: {
            attachment:'',
            memo_no:'',
            memo_date:'',
            from_date:'',
            to_date:'',
            duration:'',
            description:'',
            employees_ids:[],
        },
        errors:[]
    },
    
    mounted: function (){
        var self = this;
        // datepicker
        $('.demoDate2').datepicker({
            format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            orientation: "bottom auto",
            onSelect:function(selectedDate, datePicker) {            
                  self.form.memo_date = selectedDate;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Still removing the date... >_<

Comment: note that date value is added perfectly, but when I change any other field, the date value is removed instantly!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be a few things:

1. you are using value and v-model. Dont use value when using v-model, Set the default value when you get an error response (if you are using ajax to post) or set it with a prop if you are using a default post
2. jQuery is a DOM manipulation library, And vue uses shadow dom. They do not work well together, espesh when jQuery is setting the value of an input.

If you are using a default form to post the inputs, create hidden inputs containing the values and set the values when the date pickers change.
If you are using ajax to post this form you will not need the hidden inputs as you have all the data you need in the vue data object.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="memo_date">Memo Date</label>
    <input type="hidden" v-model="form.memo_date" name="memo_date">
    <input class="form-control demoDate2" id="memo_date" type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" autocomplete="off" value="@{{ form.memo_date }}">
    <span class="text-danger" v-if="errors.memo_date">@{{ errors.memo_date[0] }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="from_date">From Date</label>
    <input type="hidden" v-model="form.from_date" name="from_date">
    <input class="form-control demoDate2" @keyup.prevent="getDuration" id="from_date" type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" autocomplete="off">
    <span class="text-danger" v-if="errors.from_date">@{{ errors.from_date[0] }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="to_date">To Date</label>
    <input type="hidden" v-model="form.to_date">
    <input class="form-control demoDate2" @keyup.prevent="getDuration" id="to_date" name="to_date" type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" autocomplete="off">
    <span class="text-danger" v-if="errors.to_date">@{{ errors.to_date[0] }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="memo_no">Memo No</label>
    <input class="form-control" v-model="form.memo_no" id="memo_no" type="text" name="memo_no">
    <span class="text-danger" v-if="errors.memo_no">@{{ errors.memo_no[0] }}</span>
</div>
```

```
    data: {
       ...
       ...
        form: {
            attachment:'',
            memo_no:'',
            memo_date:'',
            from_date:'',
            to_date:'',
            duration:'',
            description:'',
            employees_ids:[],
        },
        errors:[]
    },
    
    mounted: function (){
        $('.demoDate2').datepicker({
            format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            orientation: "bottom auto",
            onSelect: (selectedDate, datePicker) => {
                // No need to bind this when using arrow functions.
                // You may need to find out which datepicker is changing via the event.target or datePicker to do a switch or if else to set the correct date.
                this.form.memo_date = selectedDate;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: sorry for being late, I was busy. Checking it now

Comment: checked it and removed unnecessary value, still removes the date which is the problem needs to be solved. And using datepicker like you said makes it not to work

Comment: @Psycho I would probably step away from the jquery option and use a vuejs port of it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker